# (rails) validating URL help with regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, url-validation

i'm using the following to verify if a URL is formatted validly:

```
validates_format_of :website, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))
```

however, it doesn't work when the url doesn't start with `http://` or `https://`. Is there some similar way to validate URLs with `URI::regexp` (or `URI`) and make it include valid URLs that don't start with `http://`? (For example, `www.google.com` is valid, as is `http://www.google.com`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This post on Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) provides a robust regex:

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

[A more recent post](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) improves on it (N.B. newlines and indentation added here for clarity; see the post for an even more expanded version with explanations):

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|
           www\d{0,3}[.]|
           [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)
       (?:[^\s()<>]+|
          \(([^\s()<>]+|
          (\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+
       (?:\(([^\s()<>]+|
          (\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|
          [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

From my tests `URL::regexp` is to loose in its definition of a URI (though it does require http…).

You can use a virtual attribute or `before_save` filter to append a `http://` to your URLs if necessary.

Comment: I cant get this to work in ruby. Syntax error. Could you show me how to store this in a ruby variable (if you are familiar with ruby, that is).

Answer (score 1):

This is ruby interpretation (escaped forward slashes)

```
(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)\/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+|\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\))+(?:\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)\b\/?(?!@)))
```

[Original gist by Gruber](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611)

Please copy it to [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for testing, i could not make permanent link, as reqexp is probably to long.

Works with http and without, and works with short domains like 'google.com'